# OpenFileById fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a product where `OpenFileById()` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` on files and folders that are otherwise accessible (meaning a `CreateFile()` on the same file or folder specified by path with the same access level / share mode, etc. succeeds).

I'm using backup semantics so I could also get a handle to folders; `SE_BACKUP_NAME` and `SE_RESTORE_NAME` privileges are enabled. This code works everywhere else other than this one machine (Windows 8.1).

The process is running as a service under local system, I tried having them change that to a different account with admin privileges and that didn't work either. Files / folders in question haven't been open for deletion (which is one case when this function will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` as per documentation).

I don't have physical access to this machine so can't kernel debug or anything like that. Has anyone run into this before?

Here's what I'm trying to do in a nutshell:

```
hRoot = ::CreateFileA(szRootPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

if (hRoot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR  fileId;

    fileId.dwSize = sizeof(fileId);
    fileId.Type = FileIdType;
    fileId.FileId.QuadPart = nId;

    hFile = ::OpenFileById(hRoot, &fileId, SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ...
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    ::CloseHandle(hRoot);
}
```

Comment: You've explained your problem clearly, but it's hard to help without some code. Mind posting some?

Comment: Can it be that you are working on that machine with a filesystem which does not support open by id?

Comment: That was my thought at some point, but no. Here's the volume info:
Max Component Length : 255
File System Name : NTFS
Is ReadWrite
Supports Case-sensitive filenames
Preserves Case of filenames
Supports Unicode in filenames
Preserves & Enforces ACL's
Supports file-based Compression
Supports Disk Quotas
Supports Sparse files
Supports Reparse Points
Supports Object Identifiers
Supports Encrypted File System
Supports Named Streams
Supports Transactions
Supports Hard Links
Supports Extended Attributes
**Supports Open By FileID**
Supports USN Journal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by a third party software product's kernel components (can't really go into specifics)